# A $\mathbb Z_p$-algebra homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$ determined by its value on $1+T$ (?)

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, group-rings

Let $f$ and $g$ be $\mathbb Z_p$-algebra homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_P[[T]]$ to $\varprojlim\limits_{n} \mathbb Z_p[\Gamma/\Gamma^{p^n}]$, where $\Gamma$ is the abelian group $\mathbb Z_p$ written multiplicatively ($\Gamma^{p^n}$ corresponds to $p^n\mathbb Z_p$). Is it true that if $f$ and $g$ agree on $1+T$, they are equal? I need the result when $f$ and $g$ are bijective.

Comment: Well, is it completely determined by where it sends $T$?  It's an algebra homomorphism and sends $1$ to $1$...

Comment: @D_S That would be the case if we had $\mathbb Z_p[T]$ instead of $\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$?

Comment: If your algebra homomorphism is continuous, then $$f(a_0 + a_1T + \cdots) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(a_0 + a_1T + \cdots + a_nT^n)$$ and it's still determined by where it sends $T$.

Comment: Are the elements of the RHS finite sums the form $\sum_{g \in \mathbb{Z}_p} a(g) g \in  \mathbb{Z}_p[\mathbb{Z}_p]$ ? While the RHS is $\mathbb{Z}_p[\mathbb{Z}]$ so $f$ is never bijective ?

Comment: Via D_S' comment(s), we are done as soon as we can show that every $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra homomorphism $f$ as described is continuous. For which it suffices to show that $f(T)$ is in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of the local ring on the right. Now observe that for every unit $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$, $a+T$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$, so $a+f(T)$ is a unit in the ring on the right. But units on the right are of the form $b+m$ with $b\in \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ and $m \in \mathfrak{m}$. So $f(T) \in \mathfrak{m}$. (Maybe there is a shorter way to argue.)